# Opaque panel, over the top of other controls on form, some controls are drawing over it thought?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(200, 0, 0, 0)), this.Bounds);

        Color bk = Color.FromArgb(200, this.BackColor);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bk), e.ClipRectangle);
    }
}
```

Ive applied this panel to a form.
Underneath i have other controls on the form, some seem to overdraw this new panel, even though the panel is put on the form.controls and my other custom controls are put on another panel that is then put on the form.controls. do I need to do anything specific in my custom controls to allow drawing over the top?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `.BringToFront()` method on the panel, or the `.SendToBack()` on the controls that are over your panel.

See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx).

Usually, when you add a new control, its added in front of every other control of that parent.

Comment: no that doenst work, it actually make more of my other controls draw them selves.
i have completely seperated into 2 panels, 1 the transparent and the normal and they still draw over the others.